# REST best practice for naming nested resources

Tags: api, rest

Currently I have the following resource:

```
/api/user/12
```

returns information about user with id=12

```
/api/user/12/trips
```

returns a list of trips made by user 12 and their information

However I consider /trip/ a separate resource, so this would continue like this:

```
/api/trip/5
```

returns information about trip with id=5

Is this a good way to do this?

Comment: I would say yes. It seems intuitive and unambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use plural to name resources:

```
/api/users
```

Meaning: all users (collection).

```
/api/users/12
```

Meaning: user 12.

For nested resources related to a given resource, you can do:

```
/api/users/12/trips
```

Meaning: all `trips` for `user` 12.

But, you still can describe a specific `trip` using this URI:

```
/api/trips/5
```

Meaning: trip 5.

Comment: That can be easily arranged, but my concern is that
    /api/users/12/trips
will return a list of trips vs using something like
    /api/trips/?userid=12

Comment: "/api/users/12/trips" is REST. "/api/trips/?userid=12" is not REST. That's the main difference. You should use query string for filtering purpose (like date range for example)

Comment: Here is a nice article about naming and why plurar nouns are better: http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_plural_nouns_and_concrete_names/

Comment: `/api/trips/?userid=12` not REST? 'xcuse me? It is perfectly REST. The same way that `/api/users?tripcount>0` is in asking for a list of users with at least one trip. `/api/trips/?userid=12` could just as easily be `/api/trips/?userid=12;23;19;31` asking for the trips of users identified by those userids. How you identify the resources you want returned does not say anything about an API being or not being REST. Which verbs you use and whether you use parts of the URI as a verb, does.

Comment: You're right or at least, you can't be wrong. Thing is you have "users" and "trips" resources here, so you should use them in a "resource oriented" way. That's why I said "it's not REST", it doesn't take advantage of the "user" resource. For filtering purpose (as you described with the `count`), you may be interested by  the [OData](http://www.odata.org/) protocol which introduces "system query options": http://dotheweb.posterous.com/how-to-design-rest-apis-for-mobile.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is to use the path to the domains.

To show a certain user:

```
/api/user/{username}
```

To show all the users:

```
/api/user
```

Use query for filtering all the users.

```
/api/user?region=Italy
```

Here a nice article: http://developer.immobilienscout24.de/wiki/Path_and_Query_Parameters

Comment: Isn't it recommend to avoid query strings?

Comment: Quoted from your article: "They are not intended to identify entities of a resource or to select the representation. Do not use query parameters to identify resource entities!"
I guess I would be identifying the entity user@id=12, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you were doing well. You should avoid to use query strings to identify resources, but you should use them to filter them. :)